# Source not Found in Eclipse IDE For Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I added Selenium 4.7.2 JARs to the Java project in Eclipse

When I start working and when I try to view the source its displaying the there no source file attached.

When i Googled the i found a solution which im not satisfied with.

In that article they mentioned that i have to add the source from the external location.

Comment: Compiled classes and the original sources are usually packaged separately. You can usually instruct your IDE to download the source code JARs. No clue how that is done in Eclipse though (IntelliJ user here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import source file using the 'Attach Source' button and selecting corresponding  'sources.jar' files.

Ex.

For WebDriver.class - click on the 'Attach Source' button > in Source Attachment Configuration window > External location > External File button > <navigate to the path of 'selenium-api-4.7.2-sources.jar' file and select that file, it will be available in the 'selenium-java-4.7.2.zip' file which you downloaded from Selenium.dev website>

My suggestion is to use 'Maven' project, so you don't need to download the jar files manually.